# Unity: providing an argument for an InjectionConstructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using Unity to resolve a repository that requires two factory classes in the parameter.  Below is my repository constructor:

```
//repo constructor
public MyRepo(IChannelClientFactory<IRemotedVisitorChat> chatFactory, IChannelClientFactory<IRemotedVisitorWebsite> siteFactory  )
        {
            ChatFactory = chatFactory;
            SiteFactory = siteFactory;
        }
```

ChatFactory and SiteFactory are of type `class RemotingClientFactory<T> : IChannelClientFactory<T>` that has a contructor of:

```
RemotingClientFactory(string endpointName)
```

before, RemotingClientFactory had a parameterless constructor, but in doing some refactoring, I added the `string endpointName`.

I was registering my repository like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IMyRepo, MyRepo>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(typeof (RemotingClientFactory)));
```

originally, there was only one parameter for MyRepo constructor and RemotingClientFactory didn't take any arguments for its constructor

I am getting lost in the weeds reading the Unity docs.  How can I provide RemotingClientFactory with an initialization string?

Comment: Have you tried with semi manual `InjectionFactory` approach?

Comment: I was going to use that if I can find an answer to what I was trying to do

Comment: Are `ChatFactory` and `SiteFactory` each classes derived from `RemotingClientFactory<IRemotedVisitorChat>` and `RemotingClientFactory<IRemotedVisitorWebsite>` respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to register your `IChannelClientFactory<T>` implementations, specifying the `endpointName` value to use for each. (The string values below should be replaced with the `endpointName` values you wish to use)

```
container.RegisterType<IChannelClientFactory<IRemotedVisitorChat>, RemotingClientFactory<IRemotedVisitorChat>>(new InjectionConstructor("ChatEndpointName"));
container.RegisterType<IChannelClientFactory<IRemotedVisitorWebsite>, RemotingClientFactory<IRemotedVisitorWebsite>>(new InjectionConstructor("WebsiteEndpointName"));
```

Then you can just register your `IMyRepo` implementation, the longest constructor of `MyRepo` will be selected by unity and the values be injected upon resolve.

```
container.RegisterType<IMyRepo, MyRepo>();
```